# Is it appropriate to ask for references and point to a blog with the same question

Tags: discussion

I wonder if the community would find it appropriate if I ask a question like

"

Is this or that known? It would be interesting for this and that reason. For details see our blog "blah" where we ask for answers as well.

"

The main problem I have with posting it here is that I am less interested in just having an answer, but more in pointing people to the blog post.

If I follow http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/, then I feel like it's totally okay posting the problem and the blog post directing towards an answer. I will write a follow-up meta question about that...

Thanks, Christian

Comment: If the purpose is mainly to get more people to see the blog, then I don't feel it would be appropriate here. On the other hand, if it is really to get an answer then not linking the blog would seem wrong (as  the comments on the blog might contain information an answerer might want).