# Accepting One's own Answer

Tags: support, etiquette

Is there a way to accept one's own answer?

I know, that question is a bit strange, but I can imagine situations, where that could make sense, e.g. to indicate that the author of the questions considers it as settled. That would give the possibility to better judge the nature of an answer, whether it is a step ahead or whether the goal has been reached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can [accept your own answer](https://mathoverflow.net/help/self-answer) but you must wait 48 hours before doing so.

Comment: There is no change in reputation that results from accepting one's own answer, and that answer does not float to the top (as it does when accepting another's answer).

Comment: @Francois that was not known to me; I thought it would not be considered acceptable

Answer (score -1):

There is also the concept of asking a question with every intention of answering it. You can read a bit more about that here:

[It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

We support it directly in the user interface by allowing you to check a box near the bottom that says "Also answer this question", which allows you to post both your question *and* the answer at the same time. On our very technical sites, this has proved to be a valuable feature for folks that hit those 'Eureka' moments with something interesting, and want to share what they've just discovered with the rest of the community. It's the 'blog' feature in this age-old diagram:

[image: Not *quite* the kind of diagram you think it is :)]

Whether or not this is an activity well-suited for a *very* research oriented site is of course up to all of you, I'm just letting you know that the feature is supported, and the *behavior* typically encouraged.

Comment: We strongly discourage this kind of post on MO.

Comment: I guess some relevant discussions are  http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1338/answer-your-own-question-share-your-knowledge-qa-style-is-there-consensus and http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/480/should-questions-to-which-i-already-know-the-answer-in-advance-be-appropriate-fo